# I have a crown but I am not royalty. I come from flowers and not from seeds. I am rough on the outside but I am not sandpaper. What am i?

Tags: riddle

I have a crown but I am not royalty.
I come from flowers and not from seeds.
I am rough on the outside but I am not sandpaper.
What am I?

Comment: Please let me know if you know the answer!

Comment: Hi Marie-Anne and welcome to Puzzling :) Since this is not a puzzle you created yourself, please could you let us know where it comes from? All puzzles on this site need to have their source attributed, as we have to abide by the site's plagiarism policy... Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry not too sure where it comes from. It was a riddle from a friend on Facebook.  I am just looking for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> Pineapple

I have a crown but I am not royalty.

> A pineapple has a crown of leaves on top.

I come from flowers and not from seeds.

> Unlike most fruit, a pineapple cannot reproduce on its own, often producing seedless fruits.

I am rough on the outside but I am not sandpaper.

> A pineapple has a rough exterior.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is:

> Pomegranate

I have a crown but not royalty

> Pomegranate do have a crown type structure on top.

I come from flowers but not from seeds

> I'm not sure about this.

I am rough on the outside but not sandpaper

> Pomegranate are rough on outside.

Comment: Are you willing to accept it?? Or this is not the intended one??

Comment: The answer was pineapple! 